# How to change function calls with parenthesis using composition in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Here's what I write:
 `(take 2 (repeat " "))`

I want to change it to expr without parenthesis.

Can I use "." like so:

`ceiling (negate (tan (cos (max 50 x))))` can be changed to 
`ceiling . negate . tan . cos . max 50`

But I tried `(take 2) . (repeat " ")`

and `(take . (repeat " ")) 2`
Both don't work?

Anybody help?

Comment: After the first glance at the question I thought it was about Lisp...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is

```
 take 2 . repeat $ " "
```

`.` composes functions. So here we compose `take 2` and `repeat`. To convert something bigger:

```
a b c (d e f (g h i))
a b c . d e f. g h $ i
```

You compose all the functions and the partial application of the inner most function (here `g h i`) and all but it's last argument. This creates a big function from that last argument to the end result.

Then we apply this function with `$` so that the precedence is correct. As you discovered, since `$` is just application with different precedence, you can just group with parens. But I personally prefer the `$`.

Answer (score 10):

```
take 2 $ repeat " "
```

or

```
take 2 . repeat $ " "
```

or

```
take 2 . cycle $ [" "]
```

But what you really want is:

```
replicate 2 " "
```

Which is comprised of both take and repeat as you have asked for above.

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
replicate n x = take n $ repeat x
```

Comment: BTW: If the OP had tried hlint on his/her code, it would have suggested replicate as well...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, `(take 2 . repeat)  " "` this works.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to use `(.)`, and the way to do is already posted, but if you just want to remove parentheses then `take 2 $ repeat " "` works.  The `($)` operator allows you to remove a *final* closing paren by replacing the accompanying open paren with a `($)`.